# Joining CSV files and Remove Duplicates with Google Functions

Tags: node.js, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm new at Google's Platform and I don't have the knowledge about creating Google Functions with external libraries.

I want to upload a CSV file to Cloud Storage and then trigger a Google Cloud Function to JOIN it with another CSV file in Google Cloud Storage and export the JOIN results to a new csv file and removing duplicates.

I've seen the libraries 'csv-join' and 'csv-reorder' for npm but I'm not sure about how to use it with Cloud Functions and if it is possible because I'm stuck at this point.

Thanks in advice.

Regards.

This is my code:

```
exports.Test_BQ = (event, callback) => {
  const file = event.data;

  if (file.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
    console.log(`File ${file.name} deleted.`);
  } else if (file.metageneration === '1') {


const reorder = require('csv-reorder');

reorder({
  input: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.XXXXX.appspot.com/test.csv',
  output: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.XXXXX.appspot.com/test_2.csv',
  sort: 'policyID',
  type: 'string',
  descending: false,
  remove: true,
  metadata: false
});

  }

  callback();
    };
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: promisify is not a function at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/csv-reorder/lib/read.js:6:18) at Module._compile (module.js:570:32) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10) at Module.load (module.js:487:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) at Module.require (module.js:497:17) at require (internal/module.js:20:19) at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/csv-reorder/index.js:4:14) at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

Now I'm only testing 'csv-reorder' to understand how this external libraries works. I've get results in local but no in cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The csv-reorder library uses util.promisify, which is a part of Node 8.X version, while Google Cloud Functions currently runs [Node.js v6.11.5](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#supported_runtime_runtime_updates). You can provide a polyfill to this older version via:

```
npm install --save util.promisify
```

You can then patch the util library like this:

```
const util = require('util');
require('util.promisify').shim();
```

This should solve the error you're facing. However, after having a closer look at the csv-reorder [code](https://github.com/josecarneiro/csv-reorder/blob/master/lib/read.js), it appears it can only read a file from filesystem. Google Cloud Functions doesn't provide you with a filesystem to write to so you'll need to find another way to do it.

Comment: Hi man, you are right because it only access to localsystem and finally we have changed the strategy using Google Functions.